# Windows in background end up behind the application bar

Tags: menu-bar

Sometimes windows randomly expand larger than the display area and can be seen in transparency behind the application bar (the one that is by default on the left).

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, regularly upgraded.

What could I do to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: added screenshot

[image]